# Grails logging from controller

Tags: grails, logging

I'm having a hard time to get Grails 2.4.5 to log my custom messages from my controllers into a specific file. This is what I have in the config part:

```
log4j = {
    /*
     * Log levels
    off
    fatal
    error
    warn
    info
    debug
    trace
    all 
     */
    appenders {
        console name:'stdout',  threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.INFO
        rollingFile name: 'applog', maxFileSize: 1024, file: (System.getProperty('catalina.base') ?: 'target') + '/logs/' + appName + '.log',
            layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "[%d{HH:mm:ss:SSS}] %-5p %c{2}: %m%n")
        environments {
            development {
                rollingFile name: 'grailsfile', maxFileSize: 4096, file: 'target/logs/grails.log'
                file name: 'rootlog', file: 'target/logs/root.log'              
            }
        }
    }
    root { error 'stdout'}
    environments {
        development {
            debug additivity: false, 'grails.app'
            root { error 'stdout', 'rootlog'} //override the root
            warn additivity: false, grailsfile: 
                ['org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
                 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
                 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
                 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
                 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
                 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
                 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
                 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
                 'org.springframework',
                 'org.hibernate',
                 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate']
            debug additivity: false,  applog: 
            ['grails.app.controllers', 'grails.app.domain', 'grails.app.services']      
        }
//      production {
//          root {  error() }
//          warn "grails.app.controllers"
//          warn "grails.app.domain"
//          warn "grails.app.services"
//          warn additivity: false,  applog: 'grails.app'
//      }
    }
}
```

in the controller:

```
println "Debug log enabled?: " + log.debugEnabled   
log.debug "First piggy wrote to Debug"
log.info "Second piggy wrote to Info"
log.error "And the third piggy wrote to Error"
```

That shows me "Debug log enabled?: true" on console. But the message are not logged anywhere.
The Grails internals log to "grailsfile" and also errors go to "rootlog". But appName.log stays empty.
Any hint what I am having wrong?

**UPDATE**

To simplify my request I have only configured the most important now. I want the lines

```
log.debug "First piggy wrote to Debug"
log.info "Second piggy wrote to Info"
log.error "And the third piggy wrote to Error"
```

End up in the appender applog (file)
So the log4j now only has:

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
        console name:'stdout'//,  threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.INFO
        rollingFile name: 'applog', maxFileSize: 1024, file: (System.getProperty('catalina.base') ?: 'target') + '/logs/' + appName + '.log',
            layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "[%d{HH:mm:ss:SSS}] %-5p %c{2}: %m%n")
    }
    environments {
        development {
            debug 'grails.app'
            debug additivity: false
                applog: ['grails.app.controllers', 'grails.app.domain', 'grails.app.services']      
        }
    }
}
```

But Still I get my log lines (and also errors from other sources) into console while my custom log file stays empty.

So I simply want to get (**ONLY**) my log lines into the applog appender as a first step. Any hint how to achieve this?

Comment: For more clarification I like to get the log splitted like this:
# Errors -> stdout (+ rootlog in dev) 
# my logging from controllers ->  in applog (dev) 
# all the grails stuff -> grailsfile (dev).

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the app in development mode, then all your logs with error level and higher are going to `target/logs/root.log` 
It is configured here:
`file name: 'rootlog', file: 'target/logs/root.log'` ...
 `root { error 'stdout', 'rootlog'} //override the root`

That's because `development` closure overrides your global configuration. 
If you want to see all the logs in appName.log, you should set lower logging level and change appender like this:
`root { info 'stdout', 'applog'} //override the root`

Comment: That is not what I want to achieve. 
I want for development: Errors and in stdout + rootlog, my <=debug stuff in applog and all the grails stuff into grailsfile.
For production (I know commented out above, but want dev to work first) only my logs with <=warn should go to grailsfile.

Answer (score 0):

meanwhile I could figure out that this property made the trouble for my custom log messages:

```
def appName = grails.util.Metadata.current.'app.name'
...
file: (System.getProperty('catalina.base') ?: 'target') + '/logs/' + appName + '.log',
```

changing to this works:

```
log4jFileName = (System.properties.'catalina.base') + "/logs/${appName}.log"
...

file:  "${config.log4jFileName}",
```